# Android Log After Reconnecting USB

Tags: android, usb, hid

I'm developing an Android app that works with USB HID, therefore I need to disconnect my phone from the development machine and test it. This means that I won't be able to see the log. Is there a way I can pull the log after I've exited the app and reconnected the phone to the computer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an app to view the logs directly on your device

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=de

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADB over WiFi instead of USB to do your debugging. Here is a link to a tutorial: [Android Debugging over WiFi](http://mehrvarz.github.io/android-debug-sans-usb/)

Answer (score 0):

When you plug your device ADB will show latest logs from your device (not sure how much time but enough that you will so your errors). If thats not working for you your device probably saving your application logs in phone pyhsical space (which is referenced by LogCat).

1. Plug the phone to the computer.
2. Run DDMS, select the device, and go to the file explorer tab.
3. Search for the file referenced by LogCat
4. Use "Pull from Device" to download your computer.

Comment: thanks but I can't find the LogCat file. Which folder would it be under?